# Using array to find documents in a collection using Meteor js

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, find, meteor-blaze

Helper method

```
  GetSchoolId: function () {
            var moduleIdArray=[];
            var myslug = FlowRouter.getParam('myslug');
            var mySchoolId = SchoolDb.findOne({slug: myslug});
            if (mySchoolId) {
                ModuleSchool.find({}, {schoolId: mySchoolId._id}).forEach(function (modulesSelected) {
                    moduleIdArray.push(modulesSelected.moduleId);
                });
                if (typeof moduleIdArray === 'object' && moduleIdArray instanceof Array) {
                    console.log(moduleIdArray);
                    moduleIdArray.forEach(function (moduleIds) {
                        return Modules.find({}, {_id: moduleIds}).fetch();
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Template code:

```
{{#each GetSchoolId }} 
    <p>{{GetSchoolId.modulename}} </p>
    {{/each}}
    </p>
{{/each}}
```

I know to Meteor Profs, it is a inch of an iceberg, in seconds it will be trashed. I have 3 collections, one for school record (`SchoolDb`), second for for module (Modules), and the third, a relationship table (`ModuleSchool`). modules are assigned to schools.

From the code above, I am able to get the school _id from (`SchoolDb`) using the slug passed to the route which I used to fetch the `schoolId` from the relationship table (`SchoolDb`) and the (`ModuleSchool`) to return modules assigned to a the school in question. I was able to fetch the module Ids and converted them into arrays, what I now want to do is using the array of Ids fetched from the `ModuleSchool` to return the module names from the Modules because only the `_ids` are stored in the relationship table.

The above code does only does it to the level of converting the _ids to array, when I tried printing on the template nothing showed. What wrong am I to right?

Comment: Look at [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Comment: Neil Lunn, thanks. kindly provide a snippet on the implementation based on my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find document with a field corresponding to at least one element of an array you can use `$in` :

```
Template.my_template.helpers({
    modules(){
        var myslug = FlowRouter.getParam('myslug');
        var mySchoolDoc = SchoolDb.findOne({slug: myslug});
        var arrayModuleSchool = ModuleSchool.find({schoolId: mySchoolDoc._id});
        // Transform the array of document into an array with only the ids
        var arrayModuleIds = [];
        arrayModuleSchool.forEach(function(moduleSchool)){
            arrayModuleIds.push(moduleSchool.moduleId);
        });
        return Modules.find({_id: {$in: arrayModuleIds}}).fetch();
    }
});
```

And then simply use the `{{each}}` tag.

```
<template name="my_template">
  {{#each module in modules}} 
    <p>{{module.modulename}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

But if each module is attached to only one school, i suggest a simpler solution for your problem, you don't have to create a collection between school and module.

**You just have to create two collections**: `Schools` and `Modules` and add to the Modules documents a `schoolId` field.

Then your code would look like that :

```
Template.my_template.helpers({
    modules(){
        var myslug = FlowRouter.getParam('myslug');
        var mySchoolDoc = Schools.findOne({slug: myslug});
        return Modules.find({schoolId: mySchoolDoc._id}).fetch();
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway to score this more than a point? I'm much blessed by this professional contribution. It worked perfectly..

Comment: My big thanks. Again, I copied the code to replicate for another similar scenario, this time courses to modules, my surprise is that the code did not show anything, I don't know what the trick. This is just copy and paste your answer. Like duplicating the code. Could it be a thread issue?

Comment: Try to understand how it works, check the value you are returning in your helper. Maybe you are returning nothing, so it won't print any value. Don't hesitate to put several `console.log(variableToCheck)` in the helper code.