# Doing a 1:many:many join in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, find, meteor-blaze

On this [earlier thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904934/using-array-to-find-documents-in-a-collection-using-meteor-js/45906771#45906771), some of my code worked perfectly for the scenario in question.

I want to adapt the same code for another similar scenario and I'm yet to understand what could be wrong. This time around I have a `coursemodule` collection, a many:many relationship collection between courses and modules which only stores `coursesId` and `moduleId`. Since the code worked perfectly, I simply copied, did a little modification and arrived at the code below:

```
courses(){
    var theslug = FlowRouter.getParam('myslug');
    var mySchoolDocs = SchoolDb.findOne({slug: theslug});
    var arrayModuleSchools = ModuleSchool.find({schoolId: mySchoolDocs._id});
    // Transform the array of document into an array with only the ids
    var arrayModuleId = [];
    arrayModuleSchools.forEach(function(moduleSchools){
        arrayModuleId.push(moduleSchools.moduleId);
    });
    var coursetoMod = CourseModules.find({}, {moduleId: {$in: arrayModuleId}});
    if (coursetoMod) {
        coursesArrayIds = [];
        console.log(coursetoSchool);
        coursetoMod.forEach(function (courseToModules) {
            coursesArrayIds.push(courseToModules.coursesId);
        });
        return Courses.find({_id: {$in: coursesArrayIds}}).fetch();
    }
}
```

To be specific, only 2 modules exist in the `Modules` collection, with ids - `xfLM9DEzhCMYQpQ32 and PTbZQ9cTG9pByFsY2`. The CourseModule collection has this has docs:

```
{
    "_id" : "iXX4unJZRNcCw9bAm",
    "moduleId" : "PTbZQ9cTG9pByFsY2",
    "coursesId" : "FbgcdZxADHKRBj98z",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-25T16:36:17.173Z"),
    "userId" : "n5rqFSHbhm7zqADyB"
}
{
    "_id" : "RAJJFjqAjGoDeNhko",
    "moduleId" : "PTbZQ9cTG9pByFsY2",
    "coursesId" : "ESAf6NGpZzXeioecp",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-25T16:36:17.182Z"),
    "userId" : "n5rqFSHbhm7zqADyB"
}
{
    "_id" : "8ceuFwZK8Qduo5J5P",
    "moduleId" : "xfLM9DEzhCMYQpQ32",
    "coursesId" : "KnNj4GLcyMtvF8JmB",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-25T16:38:15.368Z"),
    "userId" : "n5rqFSHbhm7zqADyB"
}
```

At the point where I log into the console I got that the `selectorId` is undefined:

> L…n.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: null, matcher:
>   M…o.Matcher, _selectorId: undefined, skip: undefined…}_projectionFn:
>   (obj)_selectorId: undefined_transform: nullcollection:
>   LocalCollectionfields: undefinedlimit: undefinedmatcher:
>   Minimongo.Matcherreactive: trueskip: undefinedsorter: null__proto__:
>   Object_depend: (changers, _allow_unordered)_getCollectionName:
>   ()_getRawObjects: (options)_publishCursor: (sub)constructor:
>   (collection, selector, options)count: ()fetch: ()forEach: (callback,
>   thisArg)getTransform: ()map: (callback, thisArg)observe:
>   (options)observeChanges: (options)rewind: ()**proto**: Object
>       view.js:30 L…n.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: null, matcher: M…o.Matcher, _selectorId: undefined, skip: undefined…}

All I want to do is to fetch the courses attached to a specific school currently displayed via the modules.

Comment: Which console is yielding that error message? The chrome debugger console? Or the `meteor mongo` console? Or the `meteor` server console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `find` function the wrong way:

```
 var coursetoMod = CourseModules.find({}, {moduleId: {$in: arrayModuleId}});
```

The `find()` function takes two parameters : `myCollection.find(query, projection)`. When you are filtering documents by field, it must be inside the `query` parameter. And the `projection` parameter is used to chose which fields to return.

In your case, here's the parameters you are using: `query: {}` and `projection: {moduleId: {$in: arrayModuleId}}`. But it needs to be: `query: {moduleId: {$in: arrayModuleId}}`

So you just have to use the `$in` **as first parameter**:

```
 var coursetoMod = CourseModules.find({moduleId: {$in: arrayModuleId}});
```

By the way, if you want to see directly the documents returned by the `find` function inside a `console.log`, use `.fetch()` :

```
 var coursetoMod = CourseModules.find({moduleId: {$in: arrayModuleId}}).fetch();
```

MongoDB find function documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: Still getting the same message on the console: ```L…n.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: null, matcher: M…o.Matcher, _selectorId: undefined, skip: undefined…}```

Comment: When i added .fetch to the query it returns an empty array. ```[]```

Comment: The first message is normal, cause find() return a Cursor object. With the fetch(), we know that it returns 0 document. You need to check more data: `console.log(coursetoMod); console.log(arrayModuleId); console.log(CourseModules.find({}).fetch()); console.log(coursesArrayIds);` While debugging, if you're not sure, check the more data you can.

Comment: The point of failure is the when trying to get the moduleId from CourseModule collection. I'm still baffled because the _id of the module I'm seeing it using Robomongo, and when i echoed it to console using ModuleSchool it shows.

Comment: If `CourseModules.find({moduleId: {$in: arrayModuleId}}).fetch();` returns no document (an empty array). Check the value of the variable  `arrayModuleId` to be sure that it contains an array of correct module ids.

Comment: Yes, it contains the values in array. And I can view the values in the collection using Robomongo. That's why I'm just not understanding whats going on.

Comment: Lets try that, is these two codes returning a value : `#1 CourseModules.find({moduleId: "xfLM9DEzhCMYQpQ32"}).fetch();` ?
`#2 CourseModules.find({}).fetch();` ?
If the code #1 returns a doc: It means that we are using the $in wrongly (with wrong data in it)
If the code #1 returns nothing and #2 returns all the docs: it means we are using a wrong query.
If both code #1 and #2 return nothing, it means that your CourseModules collection is empty, or not published to the client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152987/discussion-between-gaetan-rouzies-and-kehinde).

Answer (score 1):

@gaetan is on the right track with the answer, you need to use the query parameter instead of the projection parameter. There are some other simplifications that can be made in your code as well using the [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) library that is packaged with Meteor.

```
courses() {
  const slug = FlowRouter.getParam('myslug');
  const schoolId = SchoolDb.findOne({ slug })._id;
  const Modules = ModuleSchool.find({ schoolId });
  const ModuleIds = _.pluck(Modules,'moduleId');
  const coursetoMod = CourseModules.find({ moduleId: { $in: ModuleIds }});

  if (coursetoMod.length) {
    coursesIds = _.pluck(coursetoMod,'coursesId');
    return Courses.find({ _id: { $in: coursesArrayIds }}).fetch();
  }
}
```